# Permutation formula with multiple sets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The problem is this:

- set A has 12 items
- set B has 23 items

Taking 4 items from set A and 3 items from set B, what is the number of possible selections?

(Order matters).

I found this: [Permutation problem, combining objects from multiple sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508203/permutation-problem-combining-objects-from-multiple-sets)

Which would suggest that the answer is P(12,4) x P(23,3) x (4 + 3)!

Is that correct?
I'm struggling to understand why the x (4 + 3)! is necessary.

Comment: Order matters is $(4+3)!$ term.

Comment: Is your problem the same? The $(2+4)$ in the linked answer is used to illustrate why we need $6!$. But in that case they are taking objects from two sets and intermingling the objects which is why we get $6!$. Your problem seems to be different. If I was assigned this I would have left out the $7!$ and left it as the product of permutations because I don't see where we are asked to arrange the selections.

Comment: @JohnDouma , I think you are correct! I didn't catch that the linked problem is looking for arrangements. My first instinct was just the product of the permutations but then I was searching to see if I could find similar problems and stumbled upon that one. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnDouma: But OP has inserted *(Order matters)* at the end of the question.

Comment: @trueblueanil That's why we use permutations instead of combinations.